# Modify a field value before the element is saved

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I have a simple plugin with a field that extends the Craft PlainText field.

Is there some kind of function I can use to modify the field's submitted value before the element is saved?

```
class myField extends craft\fields\PlainText
{
    private function modifyPostedValue()
    {
        if ($PostedValue == “foo”)  {
            $PostedValue = “bar”;
            // save “bar” to database
        } else {
            // save “foo” to database
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that [serializeValue](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-field.html#method-serializevalue) is what I needed.

```
public function serializeValue($value, ElementInterface $element = null)
{   
    if ($value == 'foo') {
        $value = 'bar';
    }

    return $value;
}
```